# how can I turn Excel sheet with column and subcolmn into Pandas data frame so I can creat plots from the data

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a sheet that looks like the picture. I need to convert it to a data frame with a person number and type to be a column and subcolumn.

*excel sheet to be converted to a data frame*
[image: excel sheet to be converted to a data frame]

I tried df.stack() but that resulted in a three-column (date,person,type) data frame and many many rows that do not look like the original data sheet. I originally got 200 rows but after stack, I got 5000 rows. I want the resulting Data frame to be easy to deal with when generating plots of different types test-value throughout the study period for each person.

code

```
DSAdf1 = pd.read_excel('dsa_for_clusters.xlsX', "DSA")
df_stacked = DSAdf1.stack()

# Reset the index to move the stacked levels to columns
df_stacked = df_stacked.reset_index()

# Set meaningful column names
df_stacked.columns = ['Date', 'Participant', 'DSA_Type']

print(df_stacked)
```

Comment: Please share how you call `pd.read_excel`.

Comment: If you have already imported excel into a pandas dataframe, its not an excel question anymore. Please either ask for anything to be done on excel side or remove the tag.

Comment: read notice: [mre]

Comment: @BigBen updated the Question with pd.read_excel line and.

Comment: Have you considered using the `header` parameter?

Comment: I just try it. code <DSAdf1 = pd.read_excel('dsa_for_clusters_paper_01_03_22.xlsX', "DSA",header=[0,1],index_col=None)
print(DSAdf1)>
result 
  Unnamed: 0_level_0 Unnamed: 1_level_0  COV001   COV002   COV005 COV006  \
   Unnamed: 0_level_1 Unnamed: 1_level_1    DR15     DR53     DR15    A24   
0                 NaN                -10     NaN  3075.00  5675.50    NaN   
1                 NaN                 -9  1303.5      NaN      NaN    NaN   
2                 NaN                 -8     NaN  2302.75  2460.25    NaN 
how can I access these levels if I want to print or plot a column?

Comment: @BigBen thanks a lot. I got it. that was useful.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code:

```
DSAdf1 = pd.read_excel('file name.xlsX', "DSA",header=[0,1],index_col=None)
print(DSAdf1[('COV008','B62')])
```

by using a header you can set any rows to be columns in multi-index